# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ but Primary Key does exist in Parent Table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2012, sqlexception

Two tables: `Table1` (parent) has a primary key, `Table2` (child) has a foreign key which references `Table1`'s primary key. Upon inserting data into `Table2`, once I've inserted data into `Table1`, I get a `SQLException`:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ .

Before I execute code to insert data into table2, I check to see if the primary key exists - which will be table2 foreign key. Is there any other reason to this exception besides the obvious reason of not having a value in the parent table although I do. Thanks

I tried inserting the data in SQL Server Management Studio instead of inserting it via the ASP.NET code using the same SQL statement, but with values defined.

```
// Check to see if `VenueID` exists which does exist because the 
// dt.rows.count is greater than 0 and do something gets executed.
SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("SELECT VenueID FROM IBTCVenue WHERE VenueID = @VenueID", con);

select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VenueID", VenueID);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter dql = new SqlDataAdapter(select);
dql.Fill(dt);

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
     --do something--
}

// VenueID is retrieved from another method using 
// SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY() upon insertion of Venue.


 protected void BookCourseMethod(int ClientID, int BoomakerID, int VenueID)
    {
        SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("insert into IBTCCourse(Visible, SDate,EDate,NumOfAttendees,VenueID,ClientID,BookMakerID,Time_stamp,EventID) values(@Visible,@SDate,@EDate,@NumOfAttendees,@ClientID,@VenueID,@BookMakerID,@timestamp,@EventID)", con);
        SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("Select VenueID from IBTCVenue where VenueID = @VenueID", con);

        select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VenueID", VenueID);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter dql = new SqlDataAdapter(select);
        dql.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string DropDownValue = Request.Form["DropDownList2"];
            DateTime Sdate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["SDate"]);
            DateTime Edate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["EDate"]);
            string NumOfAttendees = Request.Form["attendees"];
            string EventID = DropDownValue.Split(',')[0];
            // string Title = DropDownValue.Split(' ')[1];

            insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VenueID", VenueID);
            insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventID", EventID);
            insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookMakerID", BoomakerID);
            // insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", Title);
            insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumOfAttendees", NumOfAttendees);
            insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SDate", Sdate);
            insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EDate", Edate);
            insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientID", ClientID);
            insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timestamp", DateTime.Now);
            insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Visible", "True");


            try
            {

                con.Close();
                con.Open();
                int succes = insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (succes == 1)
                {
                    //  Response.Write("<script>alert('The Event has been succesfully booked')</script>");
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "test", "alert('The Event has been succesfully booked');", true);
                    //clientemailLbl.Text = "";
                    //lblCell.Text = "";
                    //lblFax.Text = "";
                    //lblTel.Text = "";
                    SDate.Text = "";
                    EDate.Text = "";
                    BookieemailLbl.Text = "";
                    BookieFaxLbl.Text = "";
                    BookiecellLbl.Text = "";
                    BookieemailLbl.Text = "";
                    BookieFaxLbl.Text = "";
                    BookiecellLbl.Text = "";
                    //clientemailLbl.Text = "";
                    //lblCell.Text = "";
                    //lblFax.Text = "";
                    //lblTel.Text = "";
                 //   DropDownList2.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    DropDownList3.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    clientName.Text = "";
                    clientsurname.Text = "";
                    //clientemail.Text = "";
                    //Cell.Text = "";
                    //Fax.Text = "";
                    //Tell.Text = "";
                    Bookiename.Text = "";
                    Bookiesurname.Text = "";
                    Bookieemail.Text = "";
                    BookieFax.Text = "";
                    Bookiecell.Text = "";
                    //   userLbl.Text = "";
              //      Label1.Text = "";
                    //RequiredFieldValidator5.Visible = true;
                    //lblTel.Visible = false;
                    //clientemailLbl.Visible = false;
                    //RequiredFieldValidator2.Visible = true;
                    //RequiredFieldValidator3.Visible = true;
                    //lblCell.Visible = false;
                    //RequiredFieldValidator4.Visible = true;
                    //lblFax.Visible = false;
                    //RequiredFieldValidator5.Visible = true;
                    //lblTel.Visible = false;
                    sdtlbl.Visible = true;
                    RequiredFieldValidator6.Visible = true;
                    RequiredFieldValidator12.Visible = true;
                    RequiredFieldValidator13.Visible = true;
                //    attendees.Text = "";
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "test", "alert('ERROR 101 : Please Contact Web Administator');", true);
                //Response.Write("<script>alert('ERROR 101 : Please Contact Web Administator')</script>");
            }

            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to execute the `insert` command. Try `insert.ExecuteNonQuery();` after adding the `id` parameter.

Comment: Hi, Dan, I did execute the insert command which is part of the code i did not include here. The exception came from executing the insert statement.

Comment: Hi Dan, See edited post.

Comment: Look at the column names and parameters on the `INSERT` statement. `VenueID` ls listed as the 5th column but the parameter value is the 6th. That's the likely cause of the FK violation.

Comment: Hi Dan Guzman. im wordless actually. Feeling very stupid as well. Thank you very much.